# Sum, concatenate and merge data in several columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Need VBA macro to merge data in 4 columns. Tried to consolidate but it won't work.

Please see the picture for a better understanding. The red arrow explains what I need.

I need a working VBA to go from the 4 columns on the left to the 4 columns on the right:
Combine data (all the rows from row #2 down) by column a & c while consolidating values in column b and concatenating values in column d.

This code below is not working and is missing parts.

```
Sub CombineRows()
'This section combines and sum A and B but not C (1 to 6) and D and 
'deletes rows that should not delete instead, because of the second 
'part of the code
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim InputRng As Range
  Dim nRng As Range
   Set InputRng = Application.Selection
   Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, 
     InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
   Set InputRng = InputRng.Parent.Range(InputRng.Columns(1).Address)
     With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
   For Each Rng In InputRng
If Not .Exists(Rng.Value) Then
.Add Rng.Value, Rng.Offset(, 1)
   Else
.Item(Rng.Value).Value = .Item(Rng.Value).Value + Rng.Offset(, 1)
    If nRng Is Nothing Then
        Set nRng = Rng
    Else
        Set nRng = Union(nRng, Rng)
    End If
Next
    If Not nRng Is Nothing Then
    nRng.EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Second Part To combine A and D but it's not combining (maybe because 
'of the large amount of data and I also need the comma between values 
'in column D, not space but it doesn't work - deletes data
  Dim WorkRng As Range
  Dim Dic As Variant
  Dim arr As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Combine"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, 
      WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      arr = WorkRng.Value   
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
      xvalue = arr(i, 1)
    If Dic.Exists(xvalue) Then
      Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) & " " & arr(i, 2)
    Else
      Dic(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
    End If
 Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      WorkRng.ClearContents
      WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
      WorkRng.Range("D1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

The "Set InputRng = Application.Selection and Set InputRng = Application.InputBox" can be deleted as the range is always the same.

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Could you explain why does `vinegar` have `4` in `Field B` and `1` in `Field C` (on the right table)?

Comment: Column C has only numbers from 1 to 6. Column B can have any number. 
On the right you find a sum in Column B based on the value in Column A and C.
For instance, Vinegar is repeated:
4 times when in Column C we have 1, 
10 times when in Column C we have 2,
9 times when in Column C we have 3,
9 times when in Column C we have 4,
None (Not shown on the right) when in Column C we have 5 (because not present on the left),
None (Not shown on the right) when in Column C we have 6 (because not present on the left).

Comment: Basically I would like to "consolidate" Column C based on the combined string (ColumnA and Column C), and then concatenate the values in Column D as shown above.

Comment: Could you upload sample data so that not to enter it manually? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output goes to the same sheet in columns `F:I`. [Workbook with code](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCkx-O3caK7YYB2_YU).

```
Sub DoConsolidation()
    Dim x, r, z, field_a, field_c, vsum, id, dic, k
    r = 2: z = 1: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    '// To make code work, we need to sort data
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Key2:=Range("C1"), Header:=xlYes
    While Len(Cells(r, 1)) > 0
        field_a = Cells(r, "A"): field_c = Cells(r, "C")
        x = r: z = z + 1: vsum = 0: id = "": dic.RemoveAll
        Cells(z, "F") = field_a: Cells(z, "H") = field_c
        While (Cells(x, "A") = field_a) And (Cells(x, "C") = field_c)
            k = Cells(x, "D").Value: dic(k) = k
            vsum = vsum + Cells(x, "B")
            x = x + 1
        Wend
        For Each k In dic.Keys(): id = id & k & ",": Next
        Cells(z, "G") = vsum: Cells(z, "I") = Left(id, Len(id) - 1)
        r = x
    Wend
    MsgBox "Well done!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine now thank you, but like Michal's solution, the only problem is now with column D data. It's not properly sorting and concatenating the values (with comma - no space). It creates a sort of large number depending on how many cells is combining and also is not deleting duplicate values, increasing the width of the cells in column I results.

Comment: @MyExcelJoe You're talking about *my* solution (about duplicates)? 

Comment: I am not sure about the duplicates, but I was referring to the concatenated values from Column D cells to Column I. In Column I I get "weird" values in some cells where there are a lot of data. The cell width is huge and the numbers do not concatenate properly (with comma). Maybe a duplicate or formatting issue (but I have not formatting at all on my sheet). Please consider that I have more that 450k rows on average with more than 40k unique values in Column A, up to 300,000.00 as max value in Column B, 1 to 6 only in Column C, and values with 3 or 4 digit numbers only in Column D.

Comment: @MyExcelJoe What `column I` you're talking about? :) My code works as you need (per sample data). As I said in comment in code, in order to properly get the result, the data needs to be sorted by two columns: A and C. After that is pure cells manipulation. The Dictionary is used to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: Perhaps it's adding also a comma (formatting with comma maybe) when no comma was on the source in Columns D. Like 1000 in "D" becomes 1,000 in "I" or 2010,2010,2010,3010 (D2 to D5) for the same values in A/C, become 20,103,010 in I2.

Comment: Lastly, suppose I have 0, a letter or an empty cell, will it work anyways? I mean will it skip completely the row containing an anomaly?

Comment: @MyExcelJoe You mean empty cell in Field C?

Comment: No worries. I was able to use it. Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a different solution using a mix of VBA and formulas.  I think it's a bit more readable and certainly shorter.  Might not be a purist idea of VBA code but that's how I like to do things.  The code assumes that the input table is in columns A:D and the output will be in columns E:I - that can be changed of course.

[image]

```
Sub unique()
     Dim arr As New Collection, a
     Dim tmp() As Variant, var() As Variant
     Dim i As Long, j As Long, iRowCount As Long, iNewRowCount As Long
     Dim str As String
     Dim rng As Range

    iRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Range("A2:C" & iRowCount)

     ' Columns 1 & 3 - create unique list
      tmp = rng
      For i = 1 To UBound(tmp, 1)
         ReDim Preserve var(i)
         var(i) = CStr(tmp(i, 1) & tmp(i, 3))
      Next

     On Error Resume Next
     For Each a In var
        arr.Add a, a
     Next
     On Error GoTo 0

      For i = 2 To arr.Count + 1
        Cells(i, 6) = Left(arr(i - 1), Len(arr(i - 1)) - 1)
        Cells(i, 8) = Right(arr(i - 1), 1)
     Next

     iNewRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Column 2 - sum based on columns 1 & 3
     Range("G2") = "=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$" & iRowCount & ",$A$2:$A$" & iRowCount & ",""=""&F2,$C$2:$C$" & iRowCount & ",""=""&H2)"
     Range("G2:G" & iNewRowCount).FillDown


     'Column 4 concatenate with comma
    For i = 2 To iNewRowCount
        For j = 2 To iRowCount
            If Cells(j, 1) & Cells(j, 3) = Cells(i, 6) & Cells(i, 8) Then
                str = str & Cells(j, 4) & ","
            End If
        Next
        Cells(i, 9) = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
        str = ""
    Next


End Sub
```

Or just do it the lazy way, create a pivot table and use formulas to concatenate the strings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Michal for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't work. No results.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me within the specifications I have given above - the inputs are in columns A;D, the output in columns F:I.  You might need to change those to suit your spreadsheet.

Comment: Everything is the same, like in my picture. But I have more than 450k rows. Trying again.

Comment: Still not working. I tried everything Michal, I used less data, but still nothing populates on F,G,H, and I like in your picture. I am sorry.

Comment: Perplexing.  Can you save a copy of your spreadsheet somewhere so I could have a look at it?

Comment: Found the issues Michal. I have also numbers in Column A and Column D, and in addition it does not combine Column A and Column C when it consolidates Column B. Try to run my example in the picture and you will see that it does not produce the result on the right, in particular if in column A and C you have numbers. I am sorry :(

Comment: Another attempt.. please give it a go.

Comment: It seems to be working fine now thank you for your effort, the only problem is with column D data. It's not properly sorting and concatenating the values (with comma - no space). It creates a sort of large number depending on how many cells is combining.

Comment: What locale (language version of Excel) are you using?  Try `str = cStr(str & Cells(j, 4) & ", ")` instead of `str = str & Cells(j, 4) & ","`.

Comment: Thank you Michal for all you did. I appreciate your help.